# Issue when running xlwings python standalone fibonacci example

Tags: python, vba, xlwings, python-standalone

When running the standalone example from xlwings I am faced with the following error: [image: runtime error].

When I debug I am faced with the code falling over on this line: [image: error line]

The log file its trying to open contains the following text:[image: The log file exists but fails on the open line].

As I have just taken it from the website I dont see why its not working? It say on the web-page that it doesn't require python or the excel wings addin? Has anyone else ran in to this?

Website: https://www.xlwings.org/examples fib standalone example.

Comment: Screenshots of code are not searchable, are difficult to read, and are generally difficult to deal with.  Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54892713/edit) to include the actual code itself (in text, preferably formatted)?  Are you sure that the file has a `.txt` extension? Anything can be associated with "Text Document", and I can't tell  from the screenshot if you have known extensions hidden.

Comment: No. The instructions say only fib lite doesn't require. _Note: Except for the Fibonacci Lite example, all examples require a Python installation with xlwings >=v0.11.0 and the xlwings Excel add-in installed._

Comment: Have you unzipped the folder before running the Standalone command? The macro can't call the DLL if it's still zipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must of been something buggy on my PC and not with the programme, restarted and now it works. Thanks for the initial responses.